# OAuth 2 Web API 2 Bearer Token Two Factor Authentication 2FA

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin, bearer-token

I'm trying to implement Two Factor Authentication (2FA) in a Web API 2 solution using OAuth 2 and Bearer Token with the help of OWIN. I know 2FA with Bearer Token is not a standard workflow but has anybody successfully done this?

Basically, I have two scenarios I need to cater for:

1. User credentials are correct and no 2FA is required so return full authorized Token. This I have done and works correctly and works with methods in Web API controller that has the [Authorize] attribute on.
2. User credentials are correct but 2FA is required so I want to return a valid Token that does not give them full access, so methods in Web API controller with [Authorize] attribute do not allow access.

Once the security code has been successfully entered I want to then generate a new full-blown bearer token as in scenario 1 above and return that, giving full authorized access.

I'm using Identity 2 to create the secure code and email the code, which works fine but the area I'm struggling with is in the overridden GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method to cater for the two scenarios above. Any information or code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Need to cover the same case .. any luck?

Comment: I might have an answer to this, but it's 5:30pm on Friday.  I'll try writing it up next week.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this? I need to enable 2FA in my Web API project ASAP. In my authorization provider, I use the SignInManager class to sign-in with a password and get the result. If the result is RequiresVerification, it means 2FA is enabled for the user, I generate the token and send it via email. so far so good. The in another end-point, I verify the code, which verifies successfully, but then the SignInManager.TwoFactorSignIn() method fails saying 'User Id Not Found'. Apparently the 2FA cookie isn't being set at all, for the love of god clear this up.

Comment: @Morph are you (still) able to provide us with a write-up?

Comment: @Benji Britain Are you able to find another work around ? I need same solution. I wanted to implement 2FA for Owin Bearer authentication

Comment: Have the exact the same scenario and can't figure it out too. after 3 years no one had a solution?